# Change part of a name of a file in CMD

Tags: cmd, terminal, prompt

I'm trying to change name files, but not all the name, but only the middle part.

For example, I have these files:

```
ABC_2018_100, 
ABC_2018_101, 
ABC_2018_102.
```

And I want to change their names to:

```
ABC_2017_100, 
ABC_2017_101, 
ABC_2017_102.
```

This is to say, I want to change just the '`2017`' of each one to '`2018`'.
I want to make in the most simple way, in the command prompt.

(In the real case, I have hundreds of files).

Remember, I just want to change the '`2017`'.

Comment: What's the operating system environment that you have available? Like do you have `cygwin` available or a full fledged Unix environment by chance? If you have either of these, please update your question with that information as it should help people answer your question then for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the command prompt you can do:

```
for /f "delims=_ tokens=1-3" %i in ('dir /B') do rename %i_%j_%k %i_2017_%k
```